# How is the Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution a Chi-square Distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

This [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) states that the MB Distribution in terms of energy is a Chi-square Distribution with 3 degrees of freedom. 
I know that the probability density formula of a Chi-square Distribution with $n=3$ would then be: $$f_{n=3}(x)=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{3}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}\cdot x^{\frac{3}{2}-1}\cdot e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$$
Where $\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})=\int_0^{\infty}x^{\frac{3}{2}-1}\cdot e^x\cdot dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$.

However, the MB Distribution in terms of energy $x$ is:
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi} \cdot \bigg(\frac{1}{k_B T}\bigg)^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \sqrt x\cdot  e^{\frac{-x}{k_BT}}$$

The factor $\frac{1}{2^{1.5}\cdot \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}}$ as well as the $e^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ are missing in the MB Distribution.

Why are the formats of the formulas different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution graph (physically)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535849/how-to-explain-the-maxwell-boltzmann-distribution-graph-physically)

Comment: @Semoi I don't see how that is a duplicate

Comment: $\Gamma(\frac32)=\sqrt\pi/2$

Comment: @AaronStevens: Well, there it is explicitly derived that it is a $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: @Semoi Ah ok, I just looked at the question

Comment: @Semoi Sorry but it doesn't asnwer my question because mine is about why the formulation is different in general. However, the link says that the chi distribution is the distribution of the _positive square root of the sum of squares of a set of independent random variables_. Is this only the case if the MB distribution is written in terms of **speed**? Because energy is not equal to the square root of its square components since $E=E_x +E_y +E_z$

Answer (score 1):

Any constants multiplying the distribution aren't really important for your question, as they are just in charge of normalizing the distribution.

Distributions are typically characterized by their "shape". i.e. in your case the dependence on $x$. As you can see, both distributions depend on $x$ by the form $A\sqrt x\cdot e^{-x/a}$ for some constants $A$ and $a$, so we can consider them to be of the same distribution type.

You can also see this by taking your Chi-squared distribution, making the change of variables $x\to2x/k_bT$, and then renormalizing. This will give you the form of the MB distribution you have posted. So, you can view the two distributions as the same thing, just expressed over a different "$x$-scale" (?)

Comment: But the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Probability_density_function states that the format for a Chi-square Distribution _must_ have these factors if it's written as a probability density, even if they are constants.

Comment: @JohnnyGui Can you quote exactly where that is said? It says something like "If the constants are not these exact values then it is not a Chi-squared distribution"?

Comment: It shows the formula right under **Probability density function**

Comment: @JohnnyGui Right. That doesn't mean if those constants are not exactly the same that it doesn't classify as a Chi-squared distribution.

Comment: Ah, your edit in your answer helped me a bit. I thought the stated Chi distribution in the link is considering the same $x$-scale as any other distribution of that nature.

Comment: @JohnnyGui Ah ok. Yeah you can scale the variables and the distribution is still considered to be the same.

Comment: I have one question if you don't mind. The link **Semoi** gave says that the Chi distribution is _the distribution of the positive square root of the sum of squares of a set of independent random variables_. But that's not the case for energy since $E = E_x + E_y + E_z$ Why would that still count as a Chi distribution even though it doesn't fill the mentioned criteria for such a distribution?

Comment: @JohnnyGui Sounds like that would best be discussed on a different question.

Comment: Very well. I just noticed that when rewriting the MB Distribution in terms of speed instead of energy, it would contain a $x^2$ variable instead of $x^{-0.5}$ proposed by the Chi distribution format. 
$$P(x)\cdot dx = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \bigg(\frac{m}{k_BT}\bigg)^{1.5} \cdot x^2 \exp\bigg(-\frac{mx^2}{2k_BT}\bigg) \cdot dx$$
I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I just found a source [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YqQ-h0lJBK5EXJrdY6S4xJhKdAvnkOOz/view?usp=sharing) which writes the MB Energy Distribution in terms of the Chi-square format, but it looks a bit different than the true Energy Distribution formula. The Chi-square format gives $$f\big(\frac{2E}{k_BT}\big)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg(\frac{2E}{k_BT}\bigg)^{0.5}\cdot \exp\bigg(-\frac{E}{k_BT}\bigg)$$ While the true Energy distribution is $$P(E)=2\cdot \sqrt{\frac{E}{\pi}}\bigg(\frac{1}{k_BT}\bigg)^{1.5}\cdot \exp\bigg(-\frac{E}{k_BT}\bigg)$$ Why are they different?